# Apache 2.4 on Windows Server 2012 R2 - Error 1053

Tags: apache2, webserver, windows, configuration

I have installed Apache 2.4 on a Windows Server 2012 R2. It starts fine from the command line, and I can view test pages and what not.

I then used the command *httpd.exe -k install* to set it up as a service, and it seems to have been successful, but if I try and start it I get an error message saying "Windows could not start the Apache 2.4 service on Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion".

I also don't get anything in the error.log file.

What could I check?

Comment: That message is returned by the service manager and not an application error. When a service starts, once it has started, it is supposed to respond to the service manager that it has indeed started okay. Since the server did not respond with the very least a service *must* do upon start-up, there is nothing to report. In effect, the service is not communicating with the operating system at all. Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: @closetnoc Yes, I tried a reboot but there was no difference. Apache starts from the command line with no problem and no odd message in the logs, but I still get that error message from the Services panel.

Comment: Does Apache work anyway? This error does not mean that the service did not start. Generally it is fairly easy to convert existing code to run as a service, however, this is a Windows convention that must be followed closely and as simple as it is, if not done right, communication back to the service manager does not always happen. Apache does work on Windows just fine. However, not all Apache installs are equal. It may be a particular failure of the install base you have. It may simply not have compiled fully/correctly.

Comment: @closetnoc Yes, as mentioned in my original post Apache runs fine from the command line, serves files correctly, and runs the web app I'm developing.

Comment: I believe you missed my point. If you start the service, despite the error, is Apache working? The error does not mean that the service is **not** running, it does mean that it failed to communicate back to the service manager. This is not uncommon. If this is the case, then keep an eye on it. It may never be a real problem except for the error.

Comment: @closetnoc Ok, now I get it. No, Apache does not start at all if I try and start it from the Services panel.

Comment: Okay. Now we are past my level of expertise. I used to be a Windows expert, however, that was 15 years ago when I retired. See if you can remove the service and then reinstall the service. It may be something going wrong with the service install.